# apply a command to the values of a column in a text file and replace

Tags: bash

`cat file`

```
1   a   GYPA    
2   b   GYPA    002099.7:c.59
2   c   GYPA    002099.7:c.71
2   d   GYPA    002099.7:c.72
3   e   GYPA    002099.7:c.59
4   f   GYPA    002099.7:c.140
5   g   GYPA    002099.7:c.68
```

I have the following file I am processing. I would like to replace the fourth column with the output of `command <options> $4` as follows:

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
1   a   GYPA    
2   b   GYPA    out1
2   c   GYPA    out2
2   d   GYPA    out3
3   e   GYPA    out4
4   f   GYPA    out5
5   g   GYPA    out6
```

where out1 is `cmd <opts> '002099.7:c.59'`

This gets very complicated with `awk` since I need to use quotes `'002099.7:c.59'` to wrap the text.

I have been using:

```
t="\t"
while read -r a b c d
    echo -e $a$t$b$t$c$t$(cmd opt $d);
done
```

When the 4th column entry is empty (i.e. first line), I get an error output from `cmd <opts>`. Is there a simpler alternative to this where I could use column number besides `awk`?

Comment: Can you update your question with the expected output?

Comment: @Fredrik Pihl I added more comments. I would like to replace the 4th column with the output of `command options $4`

Comment: `echo -e` should, to a rough approximation, not ever be used at all. See the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), and the excellent answer by Stephane on the [unix.se] question [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113).

Comment: BTW, just adding quotes around a shell command you spawn from awk is not enough to make it secure against data that includes internal quotes. A variable containing `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` is going to get you either way.

Comment: ...anyhow, if you ran `t=$'\t'`, you wouldn't need the `-e` argument to `echo` to print a tab, because the variable `t` would contain *an actual tab character*, not a two-character sequence that `echo` then (sometimes, depending on both compile-time and runtime configuration) replaces with a tab character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r col1 col2 col3 col4; do
  if [ -n "$col4" ]; then
    col4=$(yourcommand "$col4")
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$col1" "$col2" "$col3" "$col4"
  else
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n'     "$col1" "$col2" "$col3"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I could probably write this into an executable